# Is there away to upgrade AzDO self hosted agents to version 3.x without removing the existing agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there away to upgrade AzDO self hosted agents to version 3.2 without removing the existing agents

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v3-agent?view=azure-devops#upgrade-to-3x-agent-on-supported-operating-systems

"If you're running your self-hosted agents on newer operating systems supported by .NET 6, **the upgrade to the new agent version is automatic**."

I ran the script referenced in the document, and all hosts are compatible. Yet, when I try to update the agents from the agents page, the latest version that get installed is 2.218.1

on updating the agent from the AzDO page, it should be upgraded to the lastest agent version